# How do i get the index of the selected playlist item

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

Hi Have created a video  play list with a pause and start button for each video.
Everything works except the changing the image of the button.

How do I get the current video index and pass to playPauseImg[0] ???

Here is some of my code:

```
<span>
    <input type="image"  class="playPauseImg" id="playPauseImg" img src="../../Icons/Play Button Green 24 x 24.png" onClick="playPauseSelect();">
    <a href="../../Bridesmaid's Entrance Ceremony Music/Angel - Jack Johnson.mp3">
        <p class="playlist_btn_text">AAngel - Jack johnson</p>
    </a>
<span/>
```

```js
var video_playlist = document.getElementById("video_player");
var links = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = handler;
};


function handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    videotarget = this.getAttribute("href");
    filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget;
    video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
    source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");
    source[0].src = filename + ".mp3";
    video.load();
    video.play();
    playPauseImg[0].src = "../../Icons/Audio Stop Button 24 x 24.png";
}

function playPauseSelect() {
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
        playPauseImg[0].src = "../../Icons/Audio Stop Button 24 x 24.png";
    } else {
        video.pause();
        playPauseImg[0].src = "../../Icons/Play Button Green 24 x 24.png";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment yet so, that's why I'm answering. I wonder when you use the id `#video_player` also it is not clear where you use jquery, please tell us why you've added the jquery tag. Plus you are not referring to your code or something what tells us what the so called video index might be.

By guessing what the answer to your question might be, I would say:
- Locate the video index
- Search for a relation between the video index and playPauseImg.
- iterate through it and put in some conditions and save the value(s).

Comment: Hi Fleuv I have been trying to find away to get the selected videos index with no success.  id #video_player is used in the following line of code:  video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
    source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");

Comment: Hi Fleuv I have been trying to find away to get the selected videos index with no success.  id #video_player is used in the following line of code:  video = document.querySelector("#video_player video"); Has I have not been able to get the index of the selected video I have a video player with a playlist below. clicking on the video name will start the video playing, clicking on another starts it playing. every video in the list has a play pause button. problem is only the first button changes the image when any of the buttons are pressed. Need to get the pressed button image to change

Answer (score 0):

What you need is clausure.

```
links[i].onclick = handler;
```

should be changed to

```
links[i].onclick = function(index){
  return function(evnt){
      handler.call(window,evnt,index);
  }
}(i);
```

Now second argument in handler will get the index and change handler to support index.

Comment: Thank you for the code pretty sure I can now get the index to the pause / play buttons. However when clicking on an item in the playlist it no longer plays ???

Comment: Hi neolivz4ever I added your code and now when you select a song it opens a new page and use Qtime player instead of html5 player.        
      function handler(window,evnt,index,e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      videotarget = this.getAttribute("index");
      filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget;
      video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
      source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");
      source[0].src = filename + ".mp3";
      video.load(); 
      video.play();

Comment: neolivz4ever I have change my links code to what you recommended however after two day of trying I can't get it to work in my function. How do I change the handler to support the index?

Comment: Are you using <audio> tag to play music?

Comment: Ohh i just saw, right now you are suing hyper link, that will just download and play. You would need to use audio tag to play music inline in the browser.